# how do i create a table partitioned by date(yearly) in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

This is my data sample

```
{"userName":"sampleUserName","DateCreated":"1519302159.248"}
```

and this is how i attempted to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE dataSet.myTableName (userName string, DateCreated DATE, email string)
 PARTITION BY DateCreated
 OPTIONS(
   description="a table partitioned by DateCreated"
 )
```

but when i try to load the data from a command line from newline_delimited_json i get this error

```
 Invalid schema update. Field DateCreated has changed type from DATE to TIMESTAMP
```

the problem i think is the DateCreated field is of type DATE, i do not know how to make it a TIMESTAMP, the documentation says to use a partition_expression, how do i do that, the aim is to create a partitioned table by date(in my case by DateCreated) for example by partition by year. how do i improve my query to achieve that, any suggestions or point me to an example or documentation would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CREATE TABLE` statement with partitioning by the timestamp instead:

```
CREATE TABLE dataSet.myTableName
(
  userName STRING,
  DateCreated TIMESTAMP,
  email STRING
)
PARTITION BY DATE(DateCreated)
OPTIONS(
  description="a table partitioned by DateCreated"
)
```

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#partition_expression) says:

> `PARTITION BY DATE(<timestamp_column>)` — partitions the table using the date of the `TIMESTAMP` column

If the intention is to partition by year, you have a couple of options:

- Whenever you insert into the table, truncate the timestamp to the beginning of the year.
- Just insert the timestamps without truncation, but when you query the table, filter by the start of the year, e.g. `WHERE _PARTITIONTIME >= '2018-01-01'` or `WHERE _PARTITIONTIME >= '2016-01-01' AND _PARTITIONTIME < '2018-01-01'`.

Comment: .consider username and Email are searchable key. How will we arrange the keys in such a way that we add DateCreated in where as clause