# How to update table data in big query?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, google-bigquery, cron

I have a table in big query where it stores employee name, id, clock in time, and clock out time. I am running a cron job that runs every 1 hour to update data in big query. The employee comes and clocks in and the record is updated in the big query when the next cron runs. I have simply passed a hyphen "-" for the empty clock out records as employees haven't already clocked out. But when the employee clocks out, a new record is created in the table. I want to update the existing record and replace hyphen with the new clock out data. I am doing this in pyhton3. How do I do that?
Can anyone help?
Thank you

Comment: you uploaded wrong data (hyphen "-") in several data sets. With `update` these can be changed.  The right data (check out time filled) is also loaded into the Bigquery already, right?  I hope your table is partitoned by date, then you can run a query for the last two days to update the missing values by the filled date value.

Comment: @Samuel i would like to know how to partition by date? any idea?

Comment: The table has to be created with partition, it cannot be done after data is filled in. Create a copy and drop the table and create it again.   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Comment: - @Dipesh Adhikari As per your query to partition by date, you can also follow this example  to create table with partitioning by the timestamp as given in this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108352/how-do-i-create-a-table-partitioned-by-dateyearly-in-google-bigquery). Let me know if that helps